# Are Field research Pokemon influenced by anything?

Tags: pokemon-go

In certain Field Research quests, the reward for completion is a mystery Pokémon encounter.

[image]

I have been doing the last stages of the *Let's Go Meltan* quest, and one is to catch an Aerodactyl; and where I live, we don't really qualify for any of the [spawn locations](http://www.pokego.org/pokedex/aerodactyl/#locations). So outside of raids or potentially hatching one, (which I don't think counts anyway), they are incredibly rare for me to find.

However, I recently completed a Field research quest (I don't know which one) and was rewarded with an Aerodactyl! I have no idea if this is linked or not, as the last one I caught was nearly a year ago, and I only just started this stage of the *Let's Go Meltan* quest this week.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Field Research rewards are indeed not random! However, it doesn't have anything to do with which Special Research you have active - it's just very good luck that you got a quest that rewards an aerodactyl while that quest was open.

Field Research objectives rotate in and out based on a schedule set by Niantic, and each type of Pokemon-awarding research will give you a specific Pokemon (or one from a very small set of possible Pokemon).

[You can see the list of currently-available Field Research and resulting rewards here](https://thesilphroad.com/research-tasks). Or, if you're interested in historical field research, Bulbapedia keeps a record of [all Field Research tasks that awarded Pokemon and the Pokemon those quests awarded](https://thesilphroad.com/research-tasks), both currently available and rotated out.

Judging by the list of currently available Field Research, I'd guess you got your aerodactyl from a "win 5 raids" Field Research.